# searching word in xml data using php

Tags: php, xml

> Actual data, update 3. 
>   Actual data,
>   Actual data,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<properties>
 <property>
 <location>
 <street-address>xyz</street-address> 
   <city-name>zyx</city-name>
 </location>
 <details>
 <price>111111</price>
 <description>xyz</description>
</details></property>

<property>
 <location>
 <street-address>xyz</street-address> 
   <city-name>zyx</city- name>
 </location>
 <details>
 <price>111111</price>
 <description>xyz</description>
</details></property>
```

I have this xml data , now i want to search in "description" some keyword like "GOOD" then how to search it using PHP?

```
<?php

 foreach ($xml->property as $property)
{

   //echo $property->details->description;

   if ($property->details->description == 'good')
      {
        echo "SUCCESFuL";
      }
  echo "NON SUCCESFUL";
 }
?>
```

Comment: Find the tag -> get its text content -> find if the word is there. What part of this process are you having trouble with and what did you try already?

Comment: foreach ($xml->property as $property) {

       //echo $property->details->description;
searching function like match or strops()
}

Comment: And how did that not work? Please, edit your question with this info.

Comment: no it says all this methods are used for array, u cant do it in xml object.

Comment: if you have any solution then can you please paste it here.

Comment: Post your code and the error messages you're getting, please. In the question. We can't guess what you're doing wrong. And "give me the code" is not going to work on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XPath, although I'm assuming there are a list of properties (I've just added another level to the source XML).

```
$data = <<< XML
<List>
<property><location>USA</location>
  <detail>
    <state>NY</state>
    <city>new york</city>

    <description> NY is good city </description>

  </detail>
</property>
</List>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$goodProperty = $xml->xpath("//property[detail/description[contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghihklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'good')]]");
foreach ( $goodProperty as $property )  {
    echo $property->location."-".$property->detail->description.PHP_EOL;
}
```

This saves having to loop over each entry as XPath does that for you and returns only properties with 'good' in the description.  The awkward part in the XPath is ensuring it's not case sensitive, which is what the `translate` does.

This outputs (for the sample)...

```
USA- NY is good city
```

**UPDATE:**

Or for a simple check exists or not...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
foreach ( $xml->property as $property ) {
    if ( stripos($property->detail->description, "good") !== false ){
        echo "Success";
    }
    else    {
        echo "Non Success";
    }
}
```

`stripos` does a case insensitive search and returns false if not found.

**Update 2a:**

```
$filename ="data.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
if ( stripos($xml->detail->description, "good") !== false ){
    echo "Success";
}
else    {
    echo "Non Success";
}
```

With data.xml containing...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<property>
    <location>
        <street-address>xyz</street-address>
        <city-name>zyx</city-name>
    </location>

    <detail>
        <price>699900</price>
        <description>xyz good</description>
    </detail>
</property>
```

**Update 3.1**...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
foreach ( $xml->property as $property ) {
    if ( stripos($property->details->description, "good") !== false ){
        echo "Success";
    }
    else    {
        echo "Non Success";
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure your XML is valid things like `</city- name>` will fail.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()